# Can we compute docker image digest before building the image to check against docker registry?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

So we have a git repository that has a number of docker images (multiple `Dockerfile`s each of which used for a different type of application build in our `Jenkins`)

Now if one makes a change in one `Dockerfile` the Jenkins job will build and pushe all other `Dockerfile`s in the repository. I was wondering, if we were able to calcualte the digest id (SHA256) beforehand and compare that with our docker registry, if there is one already we can skip `docker build` and `docker push`.

I couldn't find any command in `Docker` user guide but here with this post I also wanted to know if we can raise a ticket for this new feature if this approach works and if there is no way of calculating this [identifier](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-an-image-by-digest-immutable-identifier)

Any other suggestion is greatly appreciated

Comment: You can't know the hash before you prepare content for its calculation (build the image). If nothing changed, intermediate layers will/should be fetched from the cache and image building will be quick. But if there were changes, you have to rebuild affected layers.

Comment: okay any other suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: I would try to tackle it on repository / jenkins level. Easiest solution: Split your repository along applications/Dockerfiles (1 Dockerfile = 1 application = 1 git-repo). Otherwise: Configure Jenkins to only build the affected subdirectory in your repository. This seems a bit hacky but [technically possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44901004/how-to-only-build-one-directory-in-a-jenkins-multi-branch-pipeline-job)

Comment: @fab Thanks. Splitting the repo isn't an option at the moment unfortunately and we came up with something similar as the second option you mentioned. So we've decided to have a file name it version and every time we make a change the developer has to upgrade the version... we then check the changes being made against the file.